# Microsoft Surface Pro 3 camera not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: webcam, surface, uvc

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on Surface Pro 3. The integrated cameras/webcams are not working. Applications that need access to the cameras cannot detect them and throw errors that no supported device has been found.

How can I get the camera of this device working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Whoever closed this should have their admin rights removed.  The question is obvious to anyone.  I came here looking for this answer and my hopes were cut short by someone's arbitrary opinion.  The overarching role of admin is to make life easier for people. The 4 admins responsible for closing this have honestly, failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so after a lot of hit and trial, I narrowed down the problem to the native uvc driver not supporting the integrated webcams. The solution is to build the updated drivers from source. Open a terminal and do the following:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
./build
sudo make install
```

Restart and you are done :)

Ref:

http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

https://git.linuxtv.org/media_build.git/about/